# tomcat not responding suddenly and arbitrarily

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application running on apache tomcat. But tomcat is not responding suddenly and arbitrarily although tomcat process is running. I am unable to replicate the issue as the nature of issue is random. When I am restarting tomcat, then tomcat is starting working fine again. Can you please help me finding the root cause?

Below are the few statistics-

```
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# jps
32667 Bootstrap
3344 Jps
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      997/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30697/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21359/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32667/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30697/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32667/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1190/redis-server 0
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32667/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18186/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      997/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      21359/master
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      30697/beam.smp
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1565/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      18186/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      1633/epmd
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# ps -ef | grep tomcat
root      3538  2232  0 08:14 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
root     32667     1 85 Nov10 ?        26-05:23:24 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/root/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xms1024m -Xmx5120m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/instance2/logs/jvm/gcdetail.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/instance2/logs/jvm/ -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -classpath /root/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/root/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5 -Dcatalina.home=/root/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs#
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# nmap localhost -p 8080

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-11 08:15 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000036s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.06 seconds
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# ps -o nlwp 32667
NLWP
3854
root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# wget http://localhost:8080
--2016-12-11 08:19:47--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not with that output. Try looking at the Tomcat status page when it happens. And/or trigger a thread dump. Likely caused by database locks or memory/resource leaks, but without more information, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Try running with `-verbose:gc`. I had similar effects when Tomcat was running out of memory. But it can be just anything.

Comment: @Andreas, Tomcat status page was unavailable that time. Ample memory was free, no heap dump error found. Can you please tell me what are the statistics are required and helpful to analyze the issue. How to check database locks or memory/resource leak of tomcat.

Comment: Below are few more statistics-root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15298       2610      12688          0         12        128
-/+ buffers/cache:       2469      12829
Swap:         6399          0       6399

Comment: root@ip-10-1-201-56:~/umq-software/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/logs#
root@ip-10-1-201-56:/instance2/logs/jvm# jstat -gcutil 32667
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0.00  98.99  62.26  39.34  98.70    707    9.566     0    0.000    9.566

Comment: root@ip-10-1-201-56:/instance2/logs/jvm# jstat -gccapacity 32667
 NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC
349696.0 1747968.0 387584.0 46080.0 29696.0 295424.0   699392.0  3494912.0   699392.0   699392.0  21504.0  83968.0  34304.0  34304.0    707     0

Comment: @lexicore, gc log was fine, it was writing normal gc logs even tomcat was not responding, no exception. Also, lots of memory was available, so no question of out of memory.

Comment: Don't add extra info in comments. Delete the comments and edit the question instead.